# ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'bytes'>?

Tags: python, geopandas

The ValueError: Invalid field type  is caused at the last line of this code: `fs.to_file(out,encoding='iso8859_7')`

Full code:

```
q=gpd.read_file(fname + "\ASTENOT\simplify_centerline.shp",encoding='utf-8')
q.reset_index(inplace=True)
final = pd.merge(df, q, on=['FID_buffer'], how='inner')

#Turn it to geodataframe so it can be exported to shp
fs=gpd.GeoDataFrame(final, geometry='geometry')


o = fname + "\ASTENOT"
out = o + '\\simplify2.shp'
fs.to_file(out,encoding='iso8859_7')
```

After printing the data frame, one of the columns has be turned to this  `b'\xc5\` kind of characters. Apparently this is causing the error but I don't know how to fix it. Probably encoding issue? Tried many ways but no results.
How can this be corrected?

Comment: Can you please share full stack trace of this error

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.

It needed a different encoding than `utf-8`.
I put the `iso8859_7` when reading the file and it worked, the letters look normal and it completed the script as intended.

```
q=gpd.read_file(fname + "\ASTENOT\simplify_centerline.shp",encoding='iso8859_7')<-this changed
q.reset_index(inplace=True)
final = pd.merge(df, q, on=['FID_buffer'], how='inner')

 #Turn it to geodataframe so it can be exported to shp
fs=gpd.GeoDataFrame(final, geometry='geometry')


o = fname + "\ASTENOT"
out = o + '\\simplify2.shp'
fs.to_file(out,encoding='iso8859_7')
```